# Are there oil platforms which you could visit as a tourist?

Tags: where-on-earth

For the extreme rich there is the International Space Station as an odd destination. If you are not so fortunate could you spent some time as a tourist on an oil-platform?

Comment: Dammit, i wanted to do the 1000th question here! :)

Comment: bah, I was looking for one to ask myself too! Love the question tho!

Comment: What about [Sealand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality_of_Sealand)? It's not just an oil platform but also a micronation! (Or at least it was...)

Comment: Knew @hippietrail would bring up Sealand ... ;)

Comment: Hmm new quirky single use tags... what to do what to do... (-:

Comment: And a new *singular* tag at that!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Surprise - There is an [oil rig converted into a hotel](http://www.odditycentral.com/pics/malaysias-unique-oil-rig-hotel.html) in Malaysia, and a [Museum on an Oil Rig](http://www.galveston.com/oceanstar/) near Houston. Here is a [Virtual tour of the Captain platform](http://resources.schoolscience.co.uk/spe/ftv.html) north of Aberdeen.

Don't think you could visit a live-platform because of safety and insurance regulations - it's pretty much like asking for a tour in a factory or plant, and you would have to go through a safety briefing.

Answer (score 13):

If you wanted to visit an actual working platform, why not get paid for it?

[Dishwasher Pete from This American Life](http://www.thisamericanlife.org/radio-archives/episode/115/first-day) did it for two weeks washing dishes. You could, too!